# Pass data from influxdb to graphite

Tags: grafana, influxdb, graphite

I need to pass metric data from influxdb to graphite.

I am currently setting mock data into graphite on docker. So now, I want to integrate with influxdb because graphite can perform functions with the data like adding and subtracting values on the fly to display them in graphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is how to integrate InfluxDb with graphite, go to [influxdb.conf](https://gist.github.com/owainlewis/885f5a6a2cbd12d225c4023c6793cd5d) file. And meddle with portion specific to graphite as shown below. If you deployed InfluxDb in Linux machine, you can find the file in this path `/etc/influxdb`.

```
###
### [[graphite]]
###
### Controls one or many listeners for Graphite data.
###

[[graphite]]
  enabled = false
  # database = "graphite"
  # bind-address = ":2003"
  # protocol = "tcp"
  # consistency-level = "one"

  # These next lines control how batching works. You should have this enabled
  # otherwise you could get dropped metrics or poor performance. Batching
  # will buffer points in memory if you have many coming in.

  # batch-size = 5000 # will flush if this many points get buffered
  # batch-pending = 10 # number of batches that may be pending in memory
  # batch-timeout = "1s" # will flush at least this often even if we haven't hit buffer limit
  # udp-read-buffer = 0 # UDP Read buffer size, 0 means OS default. UDP listener will fail if set above OS max.

  ### This string joins multiple matching 'measurement' values providing more control over the final measurement name.
  # separator = "."

  ### Default tags that will be added to all metrics.  These can be overridden at the template level
  ### or by tags extracted from metric
  # tags = ["region=us-east", "zone=1c"]

  ### Each template line requires a template pattern.  It can have an optional
  ### filter before the template and separated by spaces.  It can also have optional extra
  ### tags following the template.  Multiple tags should be separated by commas and no spaces
  ### similar to the line protocol format.  There can be only one default template.
  # templates = [
  #   "*.app env.service.resource.measurement",
  #   # Default template
  #   "server.*",
  # ]

###
```

Comment: Yes i am. and thanks, i managed to run influx db with graphite enabled. but now i do not understan how do i connect the whole thing into grafana. should i use it as a influxdb data source or a graphite data source?

Comment: @PamudithaNavaratne if it helps please accept the answer and up vote.  How to use it with Graphana  is a different question, so please post a separate question. Someone knows Graphana will answer your question

Comment: i fixed the issue., the influxgraph was expecting a a graphite database and was listening to a dockerhost, not localhost. So i had to have them both on docker. Thanks again